# How to properly make Google Ads client on AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, google-ads-api

This code is being used on aws lambda for making Google ads client

```
try:
    googleads_client = GoogleAdsClient.load_from_dict(credentials, version="v11",)
except GoogleAdsException as e:
    print(f"Google Ads Exception: {e.message}")
```

Unfortunately this is running into time out issue even if the time is set to 3 minutes. As there is no error, It is not possible to debug the issue.
Any experienced developer can share some tips?
Thanks alot

Comment: A common reason for the timeout issue is a connection between Lambda and google servers. Ensure you open all the ports and other network configs from Lambda.

Comment: It has a outbound rule set as  All All 0.0.0.0/0 . So it should be good I guess. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Just instantiating a `GoogleAdsClient` instance shouldn't involve any network calls. Are you sure that this is the specific line where the timeout occurs?